# Matching random number pair game in unity 3d?

Tags: c#, scripting, uibutton

It's like any matching image game just instead of images we have random numbers. Need to create matching pair of random number game in an 2*2 matrix such that on clicking the matched pairs it should show you had won the game and it should contain timer within that you have to match the numbers. It's need to be created via c# scripting in unity 3d?

Comment: What makes you think this question is any different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040715/creating-matching-number-game-using-unity-3d ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Matching Number game using Unity 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040715/creating-matching-number-game-using-unity-3d)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write the codes for you, instead i'll point you in the direction to go in.

Create a master script that handles the game, things it needs

- int Timer
- bool isGameOver
- Random generation between 1 - 4 for where to spawn objects, cannot repeat
- 1 Gameobject to spawn for clicking
- SendMessage on player click to objects
- Player mouse input commands

Create a gameobject script that handles being clicked.

- bool isClicked
- bool isCorrect
- function that is called when clicked.

That's... about all you need, Good luck.